# QT, how to respond to message via Win32 API?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

I wrote a graphical application in qt5. I need it to be able to receive and process from an external application via the Win32 API. I was able to implement a function to receive requests, but there are some problems with sending responses to the application from which the message came (I want to send variable `result`).

How can I modify this function so that it sends back some of the data that I set in the variable `result`?

PS: an external application sends a request with the name `"MyMassage"`. I tried to send a response using various functions like `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` (some are now commented), but I did not get the desired result.

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message,
                             long *result) {
  UINT msg1 = RegisterWindowMessage(L"MyMassage");
  UINT msg2 = RegisterWindowMessage(L"MyMove");
  MSG *msg = static_cast<MSG *>(message);
  int i = 0, wparamhi, wparamlo, wparam, lParam;
  if (msg1 == msg->message) {
    wparam = msg->wParam;
    lParam = msg->lParam;
    wparamhi = wparam / 65536;
    wparamlo = wparam - wparamhi * 65536;
    ui->log->append("таблица-" + QString::number(wparamlo) +
                    " условие/действие-" + QString::number(wparamhi) +
                    " номер-" + QString::number(lParam));
    *result = 0;
    if (wparamhi == 0) // условие
    {
      if (wparamlo == 1) // таблица 1
      {
        if (lParam == 1) {
          ui->log->append("Таблица 1,Условие 1");
          *result = 1; // вернуть условие 1 = TRUE
                       // SendMessage(msg->hwnd, msg1, 1, 1);
        }
      }
      // UINT responseMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(L"MyResponse");
      // PostMessage(msg->hwnd,msg1, *result, 0);
    }
    if (wparamhi == 1) {
      if (wparamlo == 1) // таблица 1
      {
        if (lParam == 1) {
          ui->log->append("Таблица 1, Действие 1");
        }
      }
      *result = 1;
      // SendMessage(msg->hwnd, msg1, 0, 0);
    }
    // PostMessage(msg->hwnd, WM_USER+1, 1, 1);
    SendMessage(msg->hwnd, msg1, 0, 0);
  }

  if (msg2 == msg->message) {
    ui->log->append("move_move");
  }
  return QWidget::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`msg->hwnd` is your Qt app's window that is *receiving* the message, not the sender's window where you can send a response message to.

The value you assign to `*result` will be returned to the sender as the return value of `SendMessage()` (`PostMessage()` can't return a receiver's response value).  This is the preferred way to respond to window messages. For instance, since you are setting `*result` to `0` (FALSE) and `1` (TRUE), those are the values the sender will receive.

If you must reply to the sender with another window message (why?), then the initial message data needs to carry the *sender*'s window as a parameter in either `msg->wParam` or `msg->lParam`, otherwise there won't be any way for you to know which window to send a response message *directly* back to.  You would have to instead *broadcast* your response message to every top-level window on the desktop via `(Send|Post)Message(HWND_BROADCAST, ...)`.  Since you are using `RegisterWindowMessage()`, only apps that understand your message will be able to process that broadcast.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me figure it out.